# Doctrine 1.2 query with array bind

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-1.2, orange

I have this code:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('attendanceRecord a')
        ->where("employeeId IN (?)", implode(",", $employeeId));
```

$employeeId is an array of numbers

The sql output was:

```
Select * from attendanceRecord a where employeeId IN ('2,4,5')
```

but it have quote and was wrong I want this:

```
Select * from attendanceRecord a where employeeId IN (2,4,5)
```

How can I do it correctly in doctrine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('attendanceRecord a')
  ->whereIn('a.employeeId', $employeeId);
```

Please make sure you see the [official documentation](http://doctrine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#in-expressions) before asking a question.

Comment: Sorry, but believe me I've tried a lot, you see that I did it wrong